# Increase memory consumption after recreate activity

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks

My app has one activity and 6 fragment in this activity (ViewPager) , this app in normal usage uses 120MB of ram , when i close the app and reopen , memory consumption will increase (up to 200MB) and this will happen as long as I do this .

I tried :
1- recycle bitmaps after use
2- unregister listeners in OnDestroy()
3- Runtime.getRuntime().gc()
...

Android Studio profiler (first creation of activity) :
Code : 21.5 MB
Graphics 38.7 MB
Native : 14.4 MB
Java : 42.5 MB
Others : 4 MB

Questions :
1- what should I do ?
2- what's the Graphics and Java and Code in profiler ?

Thanks .

Comment: do you ever press "force gc" in memory monitor? Did you get to the point where your app crashes with OOM?

Comment: Yes I used a timer(5000ms) to run System.gc() but changes are sensible

Comment: I meant force GC button on memory monitor itself ([button 1 here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)), `System.gc()` is merely a hint that is most of the time ignored.

Comment: There's no much difference , i tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are many reason and it might be because of memory leak. If there is a leak, GC cannot help.
   Next step, analyze in detail. Like dumping memory.
   https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler?hl=en

And there is a library that help you to detect leaks.
https://github.com/square/leakcanary

2. The first link about memory profiler also describes what "graphics" is.

```
Graphics: Memory used for graphics buffer queues to display pixels to the screen, including GL surfaces, GL textures, and so on.
(Note that this is memory shared with the CPU, not dedicated GPU memory.)
```

Comment: Thanks , it was very helpful